# jQuery on click firing multiples times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tested many and many solution but any solve my problem.

I have a simple html table. Each row have a edit button.
Jquery is firing many time when I click on the edit button.

Example : I click the first time on a edit button, all work fine. After that, I click on a second edit button and then jquery is firing 2 time, ...

```
$('.edit').one('click', function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            $(this).unbind('click');

            var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            var saveUrl = $(this).attr('href');

            $('.form-edit').submit(function(e)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();

                 console.log($('.form-edit').serialize());

            });
        });
```

stopPropagation, return false, unbind, ... change nothing.

What is the problem with my code ?

Comment: Why are you doing `$(this).unbind('click');` when you are already using `.one()`?

Comment: Do you use .edit class multiple times?

Comment: yes i use edit class multiples time i have 100 entry in my table.

Comment: I tested also one in place of on ... it change nothing

Comment: could you try delegating the event. Use `$('table').on('click', '.edit', function(){})`? It's much better, especially with hundreds of table rows

Comment: Was just going to suggest the same thing as @skip405.

Comment: Try to reproduce the issue in a https://jsfiddle.net, this way it's easier to us know what's going wrong

Comment: It seems like you are registering an event handler to the edit-button multiple times, but it is not obvious in the code you provided...

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/5g6xb933/ All your solutions doesn't work in my case :-(

Comment: You're binding a new submit handler to the element `.form-edit` after every single click event from the `.edit` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply resolved with this code : `unbind then bind`

```
$('.form-edit').unbind('submit').bind('submit', function(event)
{
 ...
}
```